# ExecuteMany inserts wrong value

Tags: node.js, json, oracle, node-oracledb

I am using oracledb (4.0.1) with node (v10.14.2). I have json list down below;

```
[ { DIFFID: 8,
    DIFFDATE: 2019-11-01T14:04:41.831Z,
    REGIONNAMEA: 'TURKEY',
    VENDORA: 'XXX',
    SOURCECOUNT: 797,
    DIFFCOUNT: 8,
    PERCENTAGE: 99 },
  { DIFFID: 8,
    DIFFDATE: 2019-11-01T14:04:41.831Z,
    REGIONNAMEA: 'GERMANY',
    VENDORA: 'XXX',
    SOURCECOUNT: 440,
    DIFFCOUNT: 8,
    PERCENTAGE: 98.18 },
  { DIFFID: 8,
    DIFFDATE: 2019-11-01T14:04:41.831Z,
    REGIONNAMEA: 'FRANCE',
    VENDORA: 'XXX',
    SOURCECOUNT: 206,
    DIFFCOUNT: 5,
    PERCENTAGE: 97.57 } ]
```

By oracledb executeMany method, i will insert that json list to db. Here is how i call that function below;

```
const saveManySla = async (config, jList) => {
  let test = [];
  let connection;
  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(config);
    test = await connection.executeMany(
      `
    INSERT INTO DAILY_DIFF_SLA 
      VALUES (SEQ_DAILY_DIFF_SLA.NEXTVAL, :DIFFID, :DIFFDATE, :REGIONNAMEA, :VENDORA, :SOURCECOUNT, :DIFFCOUNT, :PERCENTAGE)
      `,
      jList,
      {
        autoCommit: true
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    log.error(err, 'ora.saveManySla');
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      connection.close();
    }
  }
  return test;
};
```

By the way I used that executeMany method many times before first time i had issue like that. It inserted json list wrongly. Here is how it looks like on DB down below;

```
ID |DIFF_REPORT_ID|DIFF_DATE          |REGION        |VENDOR |SOURCE_COUNT|DIFF_COUNT|PERCENTAGE         |
---|--------------|-------------------|--------------|-------|------------|----------|-------------------|
139|             8|2019-11-04 11:09:12|TURKEY        |XXX    |         797|         8|                 99|
140|             8|2019-11-04 11:09:12|GERMANY       |XXX    |         440|         8|4636609220240232940|
141|             9|2019-11-04 11:09:13|FRANCE        |XXX    |         206|         5|              97.57|
```

If i filter by "GERMANY" my json list just have one item. Then i use executeMany method it records correct.

```
ID |DIFF_REPORT_ID|DIFF_DATE          |REGION        |VENDOR |SOURCE_COUNT|DIFF_COUNT|PERCENTAGE         |
---|--------------|-------------------|--------------|-------|------------|----------|-------------------|
142|             8|2019-11-04 11:19:12|GERMANY       |XXX    |         440|         8|              98.18|
```

PERCENTAGE column Data Type is **Number**.

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to issues with decimal conversion. Could you please try the following: Change the insert to expect decimals as strings and convert using to_number. For example, `to_number(:PERCENTAGE)`. Then, before passing `jList` to `execute`, convert the decimals to strings. Let us know how that goes.

Comment: @DanMcGhan i tried what u guessed it didnt help to me. While i was trying to fix it, i realized that when i prepare my json i was casting PERCENTAGE property to Number. I removed that cast then i tried it saved correctly on Db. So i solved it by myself but i'm not sure why it happend. Here is code that i changed. ````temp.PERCENTAGE = ((1 - (temp.DIFFCOUNT / temp.SOURCECOUNT).toFixed(4)) * 100).toFixed(2);````

Comment: When you use `toFixed`, you're converting the number to a string. This is what I suggested. The explicit use of to_number isn't truly needed since Oracle will do this implicitly.

Comment: after i used ````toFixed```` i didnt convert it to number on js. Then it records correct.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have proper decimal support yet. Convert the numbers in JavaScript to strings to avoid conversion errors. Then convert the strings to Oracle numbers within the database.